# Server is unwilling to process the request for ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I try create a user in AD.

Now, I get the error:

> 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A1248, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
>
> Server is unwilling to process the request
>
> Translate: El servidor no puede procesar la solicitud.

My actual legacy code (main fragment):

```
        SearchResult ret = searcher.FindOneReturningDirectorySearchResult();
        if (ret == null)
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException("group", searcher.GetFilter());
        using (DirectoryEntry parent = ret.GetDirectoryEntry())
        {
            parent.RefreshCache();
            using (DirectoryEntry newUser = parent.Children.Add("CN=" + this.CommonName, CommonPropertyNames.ObjectClassNames.UserObjectClassName))
            {
                Utility.SetProperty(newUser, UserPropertyNames.Name, this.CommonName);
                Utility.SetProperty(newUser, "userPassword", "Cambia$123");
                FillUserProperties(newUser);
                newUser.CommitChanges();
```

> Note: `newUser.CommitChanges()` throws the error.

Now, if I try using **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement** is `working`. Not errors, all is OK.

```
         string OuDnDES = "OU=Portal,OU=NSI DESARROLLO,DC=company,DC=net";
        using (var pc = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain,
            "mydomain.net",OuDnDES, "mydomain\\DES_GestorDirectorio", "1234"))
        {
            using (var up = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal(pc))
            {
                up.SamAccountName = "testAD001";
                up.EmailAddress = "test@realexx.es";
                up.SetPassword("Change$123");
                up.Enabled = true;
                up.ExpirePasswordNow();
                up.Save();
            }
        }
```

I cannot use **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement**, my versión prior NET 3.5.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually means, that some mandatory attributes for the object being created are not set. Try to set sAMAccountName attribute

```
    SearchResult ret = searcher.FindOneReturningDirectorySearchResult();
    if (ret == null)
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException("group", searcher.GetFilter());
    using (DirectoryEntry parent = ret.GetDirectoryEntry())
    {
        parent.RefreshCache();
        using (DirectoryEntry newUser = parent.Children.Add("CN=" + this.CommonName, CommonPropertyNames.ObjectClassNames.UserObjectClassName))
        {
            Utility.SetProperty(newUser, UserPropertyNames.Name, this.CommonName);
            Utility.SetProperty(newUser, "userPassword", "Cambia$123");
            Utility.SetProperty(newUser, "sAMAccountName", "testAD001");
            FillUserProperties(newUser);
            newUser.CommitChanges();
```